# Search a sample of image floating left in vuetify

Tags: image, css-float, vuetify.js

In my Laravel 5.6/“vue”: "^2.5.7/“vuetify”: “^1.0.8” application I search a sample of image floating left
and text at right with card implementation.
I searched [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards#introduction) and did not find…
Could you please give a ref to example?

MODIFIED :

I mean html code like with long text:

```
<div class="card">

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <a class="a_link" target="_blank" href="/storage/votes/-vote-14/mammals.jpg">
                            <img class=" pull-left img-medium-preview" src="/storage/votes/-vote-14/mammals.jpg" alt="Which is the tallest mammal?" width="423" height="280">
                        </a>


                    <div>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Which is the tallest mammal?</h5>

                        <p class="card-text">
                            Which is the tallest mammal lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

and it looks like that with text floating the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVa1D.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuetify has a class `left` which applies `float: left !important`.
We can use that on the `img` (but not if it's inside a container which has `display: flex`), and then the text will wrap around the image.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJJbVL)

And add some style to make it act responsively:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%; 
   height: auto;
}
```

---

In vuetify version `^1.2.0` You can use `v-img` component which makes it easier to place images.

`v-card` and it's child components don't have specific props for this behavior afaik, so you can use arbitrary layout inside the card.

```
<v-card>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs5>
      <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/desert.jpg"></v-img>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs7>
      <v-card-title primary-title>
        <div>
          Text
        </div>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-card>
```

Then take a look at [`v-img` props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images) and style the image as you see fit.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeeQRZ)

---

If you are not using `v-img` then you have to use custom CSS for styling your image.

Comment: This example with link to codegen willnot work witrh big block of text like https://codepen.io/icsvetkov/pen/OooaYN.  The text block will be at right, but not floating

Comment: @Ivan Hm, could you elaborate what do you mean by "floating"? Any other (perhaps even non-vuetify) example which shows what you'd like to achieve? Because afaiks we shouldn't use `float` css property in flex, so probably you mean something else? Perhaps you meant ["sticky"](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mqqxpp)?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED block of original text

Comment: @Ivan Vuetify has a class `left` which applies `float: left !important` so perhaps you could use that on the `img`? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJJbVL

Comment: Thank you !
I made like that https://codepen.io/sergeynilov/pen/oPaNoa
Also I need to add margin near with image, but I failed. Which is valid way?

Comment: See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing#how-it-works Just put e.g. `ma-1` class on the image component to apply **m**argin at **a**ll directions.

Comment: Super useful! I took this one step further and since I was using a v-for loop and wanted to have the images on the left for every other image I applied Vuetifies helper class "flex-row-reverse" only to every other card.